# Cannot use mean absolute error metric (mae) in python XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm starting with XGBoost and willing to use it for a regression problem.

My evaluation metric is mean absolute error (mae). As far I understand, we can use XGB with this metric (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md#learning-task-parameters).

I tried using XGB CV with the parameter `metrics = ['mae']` but I get an error that says mae metric doesn't exist: `XGBoostError: unknown evaluation metric type: mae`

Here is my code:

```
xgdmat = xgb.DMatrix(train, y_train)

our_params = {'eta': 0.5,
              'seed': 0,
              'subsample': 1,
              'colsample_bytree': 1, 
              'max_depth': 3,
              'min_child_weight': 3,
              'objective': 'reg:linear'} 

cv_xgb = xgb.cv(params = our_params, dtrain = xgdmat, num_boost_round = 3000, nfold = 5,
                metrics = ['mae'],
                early_stopping_rounds = 100)
```

Did anyone already faced this issue and can help me solve this ?

Many thanks.

Comment: I figured out it's a version problem (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1138). I had to reinstall XGB from the official GitHub repo.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it. Also, please actually state the version/date involved. Does this work in 0.4.4? 0.6? neither?